# Call Subroutine from a string value VBA

Tags: vba, excel

trying to call this subroutine using a string. I have tried Application.Run like I have read online but that doesn't seem to be working. 
The variable element will loop through and represents different state codes. So I have subs called "CA_Config", "GA_Config" "AZ_Config" etc.

```
Dim strSubToCall As String
strSubToCall = element & "_Config()"
Application.Run strSubToCall
```

State subs are very different therefore need to be different subroutines. The other subs and the main sub calling the other ones are all public.

Example for CA sub below

```
Public Sub CA_Config()

Dim rngLastHeader As Range
Dim intLastRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
intLastRow = Sheet1.currWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set rngLastHeader = Sheet1.currWS.Range("A1").End(xlToRight)

rngLastHeader.Offset(, 1).Value = "Use Tax Reversal Needed"

Sheet1.currWS.Range("X:X").EntireColumn.Copy
Sheet1.currWS.Range("Y:Y").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Sheet1.currWS.Range("Y:Y").Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove parenthesis `()`

Comment: That's what I tried first and didn't work either :(

Comment: Perhaps, the `Sub` is in another module and `Private`?

Comment: Same module and public!

Comment: Define "doesn't seem to be working"

Comment: Instead of having different subs for each state, have **one** sub with a parameter....  ie., `Sub StateConfig("CA")`  How different are each of these "state subs"?

Comment: It runs through the line, doesn't error out, but instead of jumping to Public Sub CA_Config() it goes to the next line after Application.Run line

Comment: Prepend your `Sub` with module name. For instance, `Application.Run "Module1.MySub"`

Comment: That was it! I added the module name and it called, thank you @JohnyL

Comment: @SanomaJean You're welcome! :)

Comment: Do you have separate sub's for every state?  I suspect there's an easier way...   :-)

Comment: @ashleedawg for about 20 of them... I know there definitely should be... : | They're all extremely customized based on counties, cities, type of sale, tax rate, etc. I will probably get it done this scrappy way then look for a way to improve once it's functioning!

Comment: @SanomaJean nice, good call :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove parenthesis and prepend your Sub name with module name. For instance, `Application.Run "Module1.MySub"`.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Please, follow comments under the question - the parenthesis were the first thing I mentioned.

Comment: Interesting. I did test with `application.run "some unqualified public procedure I have in my current project"` and it *was* invoked, and still is if I try it again. However it doesn't like `application.run "sub1"` for some reason. As I said, qualifying the member with its parent module is always a good idea. I didn't ask you to change your answer, I asked you to edit so as to include the part about the parentheses, which you did, which prompted my vote's reversal. Damn you having a bad day or something? Cheers mate.

Comment: Try renaming your `Sub1` to `DoSomething` and your `Sub2` to `AnotherThing` - and bow to the stupidity of the VBE.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Didn't mean to offense, mate :) This is the moment when I spot a bug - for some reason, subs with names like Sub*N* don't get called, but 
"SubCool" works well. H-m-m. This is really strange. :(

Comment: Indeed, looks like a bug. Not in the VBE though - `Application.Run` is entirely Excel's object model. So, it's a bug in Excel, not in the VBE. But if you tell Microsoft I bet they'll call it a feature ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Ahaha) They will fix it ASAP for sure :)

Comment: Another interesting bit: `Public Sub Sub1234()` is listed in Excel's "macros" list, but the macro dialog's "Run" button is disabled when it's selected, which confirms my long-standing suspicion that Excel's "Run Macro" tool uses `Application.Run` under the hood. Yet another good reason to *use meaningful names*!

Comment: `Sub1` through `Sub1048576` won't work, but use a numbering scheme above 2^20, and `Sub1048577` will work just fine. It's obvious, right?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Oh wait, duh, "Sub1" is a valid *cell address*, where the `Macro` argument to `Application.Run` *can* be a Range (presumably to facilitate Excel4 Macros?), and (according the help) when that argument is a string, it is in the context of the active sheet. Yet another instance of name clashes once Excel bumped the row/column counts in 2007. There are a bunch of new inspections for [Rubberduck VBA](http://www.rubberduckvba.com) to handle ;-)

Comment: @ThunderFrame Yes, indeed the problem is with clash between address cell and Sub name. One needs to add module name before Sub name. :)